# Loading svg or image to UIWebview but not showing UIWebView to MainView

Tags: objective-c

I'm curious is there would be a problem regarding loading images or svg codes to a webview when the webview is not being shown? because i'm planning on making the webview a holder of the svg then have the webview converted to UIImage. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with images, UIWebView works pretty much like Safari, raw HTML image should display with no code rendering a page. SVGs should work too however they may blow up if the SVG doesn't have a fixed size.

One thing to try is use iOS Simulator and drag and drop assets into the Simulator, by default it should launch mobile safari and show what you need to test in a UIWebView, this works well for testing assets outside of HTML content in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *fileURL =[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:SVGpath];
NSURLRequest*req =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[webView loadRequest:req];

//uncheck opaque property of UIWebView.
```